# Extracting data from a log file

Tags: python

I have a `log.txt` file like this,

```
2022-10-12 18:15:22.992 0026/? I/AsrDecActor25: channels=1, size=82434
2022-10-12 18:15:22.992 0026/? I/AsrDecActor25: waiting asr-core ready: 12 secs
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: asr state: START, true
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: asr state 2: START
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: end of decoding 57 true 0
NEC Input :secure folder app close it
NEC Replacement suggestion :Secure folder
NEC Input Before Replace : secure folder app close it
NEC Matching Word : secure folder app
Replaced Word  : Secure folder
NEC Output After Replace : Secure folder close it
Changes : 1
2022-10-12 18:15:23.060 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [NEC] Run completed, Time: 2 ms
PostProcessSubstitutions::Output of question mark processing: secure folder uninstall Kare
[eITN] Input:Secure folder uninstall kare OutputSecure folder uninstall Kare
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [Timestamp] getTimestamp starts
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR levenshteinMapping
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR new ASRResult
2022-10-12 18:15:23.091 0021/? I/AsrDecActor26: decoding
```

Now I have written a code to extract the lines with beginning "NEC Input Before Replace" and "NEC Matching Word" such that my output.txt file looks like this

```
NEC Input Before Replace : secure folder app close it
NEC Matching Word : secure folder app
```

At first the code which I had written for the same was

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
f = open('log.txt')
f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')

doIHaveToCopyTheLine=False

for line in f.readlines():

    if 'NEC Input Before Replace' in line:
        doIHaveToCopyTheLine=True
    elif 'NEC Matching Word' in line:
        doIHaveToCopyTheLine=True

    if doIHaveToCopyTheLine:
        f1.write(line)

f1.close()
f.close()
```

which was throwing me this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 7>()
      3 f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')
      5 doIHaveToCopyTheLine=False
----> 7 for line in f.readlines():
      9     if 'NEC Input Before Replace' in line:
     10         doIHaveToCopyTheLine=True

File D:\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py:23, in IncrementalDecoder.decode(self, input, final)
     22 def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23     return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 7524: character maps to <undefined>
```

So i changed the code to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
f = open('log.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')

doIHaveToCopyTheLine=False

for line in f.readlines():

    if 'NEC Input Before Replace' in line:
        doIHaveToCopyTheLine=True
    elif 'NEC Matching Word' in line:
        doIHaveToCopyTheLine=True

    if doIHaveToCopyTheLine:
        f1.write(line)

f1.close()
f.close()
```

Though the file is opening currently but in the output I am getting this

```
NEC Input Before Replace : secure folder app close it
NEC Matching Word : secure folder app
Replaced Word  : Secure folder
NEC Output After Replace : Secure folder close it
Changes : 1
2022-10-12 18:15:23.060 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [NEC] Run completed, Time: 2 ms
PostProcessSubstitutions::Output of question mark processing: secure folder uninstall Kare
[eITN] Input:Secure folder uninstall kare OutputSecure folder uninstall Kare
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [Timestamp] getTimestamp starts
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR levenshteinMapping
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR new ASRResult
2022-10-12 18:15:23.091 0021/? I/AsrDecActor26: decoding
```

All the lines after my desired lines are also getting printed. Anyone knows why is this happening and how to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to reset `doIHaveToCopyTheLine` to `False` at the beginning of each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reset `doIHaveToCopyTheLine` to `False` outside the loop, before you start iterating.

Instead, you need to do it inside the loop, at the beginning of every iteration.

But you may as well just do:

```
if 'NEC Input Before Replace' in line or 'NEC Matching Word' in line:
    f1.write(line)
```